# Access lastScheduledTime from cron workflow

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I'm trying to implement automatic backfills in Argo workflows, and one of the last pieces of the puzzle I'm missing is how to access the `lastScheduledTime` field from my workflow template.

I see that it's part of the template, and I see it getting updated each time a workflow is scheduled, but I can't find a way to access it from my template to calculate how many executions I might have missed since the last time the scheduler was online.

Is this possible? Or maybe, is this the best way to implement this functionality on Argo?